# Getting this.id on model validation returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting `this` as `undefined` on field's validate, but the same occurs even if I set in third argument of `Sequelize.define`to use other fields as [documentation](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/models-definition/#validations) describes.

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

const User = sequelize.define(
    'User', 
    {...}, //all fields here
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: true,
        validate: {
            isPasswordRepeated: () => {
                console.log(this.id, this.password);
            }
        }
    }
);

}
```

In this code, `console.log` outputs `undefined undefined`. If I use on password's validate, still gets `undefined` for `this.id`, but receives password through argument.
I've looked for solutions, but it seems a rare problem and only found [this abandoned issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4447) on GitHub. Is there another way to get `this.id`?

Sequelize version 4.42.0

Comment: id is coming from what?

Comment: I'm trying to get `this.id` to get the id from the instance that is being validated, as [documentation](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/models-definition/#validations) describes to do.

Comment: What is the scope of ```this```?

Comment: Sequelize.define is inside of the following scope `module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) { .... }`
I'll update the question now.

Comment: Docs provided by you are for v2.0, I dont think it is correct with v4.42. Check http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html, it is official docs for actual version. For example for model attribbutes definition is uset `init` function, not `define`

Comment: But [it still says](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html#model-wide-validations) to use `this` on `validate`.

Comment: Note the difference between that documentation and your code: the documentation does not use an arrow function...

Comment: Oh, I think I'm getting where you all are trying to get me to. I was confused, because all over the code there is the usage of `this`, but they were accessed through User.prototype.whatever, so getting by this old way I can't get `this` in the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You're not understanding the context of 'this'.

> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is
>   called.
>
> ...
>
> Since the following code is not in strict mode, and because the value of 
>   this is not set by the call, this will default to the global object, which 
>   is window in a browser.
>
> ...
>
> In strict mode, however, if the value of this is not set when entering
>   an execution context, it remains as undefined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, jeez.. I tried to edit it, but you didn't even give me 30 seconds. ;)

Comment: Sorry, it's such a common thing it's muscle memory at this point :).